# How to use global actions declared inside a nested graph from the outer graph?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I tried to use a [global action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) using Safe Args with nested graphs but I got an error.

*FragmentA.kt*:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        btFragmentB.setOnClickListener {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
                .navigate(FragmentBDirections.actionGlobalFragmentB())
        }
    }
}
```

*FragmentB.kt*:

```
class FragmentB : Fragment()
```

*main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.cookpad.arcshowcase.stack.FragmentA"
        android:label="FragmentA" />

    <include app:graph="@navigation/fragment_b" />
</navigation>
```

*fragment_b.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentB">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.cookpad.arcshowcase.stack.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_fragmentB"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
</navigation>
```

When I run this, I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.cookpad.arc:id/action_global_fragmentB is unknown to this NavController` Which seems to indicate that the action_global_fragmentB was never merged from the sub-graph.

**Is there a way to use global actions declared inside a nested graph from the outer graph?**

Comment: Hi! Did you found a solution?

Comment: Not exactly xD I just used one single graph for the whole app, that made things easier at multiple levels.

Comment: In case someone may find interesting having a general picture of the whole navigation component -> https://sourcediving.com/navigating-towards-a-new-navigation-154011622435

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your global action to the main graph nav

**main.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.cookpad.arcshowcase.stack.FragmentA"
        android:label="FragmentA" />

    <include app:graph="@navigation/fragment_b" />

    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_global_fragmentB"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_b" />
        
</navigation>
```

fragment_b.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentB">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.cookpad.arcshowcase.stack.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB" /> 

</navigation>
```

**FragmentA.kt**

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btFragmentB.setOnClickListener {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
                .navigate(FragmentADirections.actionGlobalFragmentB())
        }
    }
}
```